# Was upon ever pronounced like up-on?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Apparently, the word *upon* has its origin in the words *up* and *on*. Since I recently heard a non-native speaker pronounce *upon* as ['ʌpɒn], I would like to know if there is any record regarding the evolution of its pronunciation. Was (or is) it ever commonly pronounced in this way?

Comment: The answer is undoubtedly "If so, then a very long time ago". OED has an entry from 1272 - *Luue Ron 121 in Old Eng. Misc. 97   Hit stont vppon a treowe mote.*

Comment: 'There is a hammer up on the top shelf' is quite acceptable. Are you sure the speaker really _was_ aiming for 'upon'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, but as I pointed out, he was not a native speaker. He used phrases such as "upon adding x to y" etc.